# jqGridmin.js produce error in FF when doing quick switching between grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I'm attempting to switch between filters and loading up different jqGrids in succession, I sometimes get this error in FF:

i.p is undefined (line 108), which is this line:

```
j.p.lastsort=b.inArray(j.p.lastsort,f);if(j.p.treeGrid)j.p.expColInd=b.inArray(j.p.expColInd,f)},setGridWidth:function(f,k){return this.each(function(){var i=this,h,g=0,j=i.p.cellLayout,m,a=0,q=false,t=i.p.scrollOffset,x,C=0,K=0,J=0,F;if(i.grid){if(typeof k!="boolean")k=i.p.shrinkToFit;if(!isNaN(f)){f=parseInt(f,10);i.grid.width=i.p.width=f;b("#gbox_"+i.p.id).css("width",f+"px");b("#gview_"+i.p.id).css("width",f+"px");b(i.grid.bDiv).css("width",f+"px");b(i.grid.hDiv).css("width",f+"px");i.p.pager&&
```

Any clues on how to avoid this? It is a difficult to replicate bug cos I really have to switch quickly between the filters to sometimes get this error.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? You wrote about switching between grids in the question title and about switching between filters in the text. When you have the error? To find the error you should include the JavaScript code which use jqGrid. Moreover you should try with uncompressed version on jqGrid, then you will see the place of code where the error is.

Comment: using the latest version. should have been more specific - different filters generate different grids in my case, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem which was a function that was called on grid complete to setGridWidth. Somehow even though the grid was 'complete', the setGridWidth couldn't get the grid to adjust .. maybe because of the delay it takes for the grid to render after ajax complete/success.

A bit of background: I use the jqGrid set width function after grid complete to determine whether horizontal scrollers are needed. (A lot of customisation there...)